# What does "as big around as you can reach" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

It is a quote by Lao-Tze:

> A tree as big around as you can reach starts with a small seed; a thousand-mile journey starts with one step"

I understand what the quote is trying to get at, but I don't understand what "as big around as you can reach" means literally.

Comment: It means literally the thing it literally means. Every word of the seven is used in its literal sense. Please specify which word we need to explain, as well as what you think it means and why you think what you think is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I mean, does it mean that the tree has a large radius ? So big that you couldn't even wish to circumnavigate it ? Or does it mean something else ?

Comment: 'Reach [around the tree] by spreading your arms around it', not 'circumnavigable by someone who can walk normally'.

Comment: There is No indication of the research you did to try to find a similar phrase, or what if anything is causing you a problem. The question reads like, I don't know what it means, please go and find out for me!

Comment: @Brad I did. If a piece of text at the beginning of the question saying "I looked online for the meaning of the expression 'as big around as you can reach' but found nothing similar" would be of any comfort, I will add it in. English is not my first language and so some expressions sound unnatural to me, and I may at times incorrectly estimate the difficulty of them. If this is more fit for the other community (the one more related to learning English), then I apologize thoroughly.

Comment: Looking up "as big around as" in a Google search gives "as big around as a truck wheel", "as big around as my wrists" and "as big around as a large can of tomatoes" among the first 15 or so of 500 000 hits. This strongly suggests (a) circumference is meant, and (b) the expression is commonly used (in various forms). Admittedly, there are more confusing examples, and 'as you can reach' isn't totally transparent, but the first sentence above constitutes reasonable evidence of reasonable research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did know that circumference was meant, I just didn't know the hands were involved, and it doesn't make sense if the hands aren't involved.

Comment: But you didn't add requisite _evidence_ (not just "I knew / I looked ...") of your research.

Comment: I am sorry. I thought it was a difficult question and therefore would be a great addition to the site as opposed to a burden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lesson contrasts things large and small. The long journey of many steps starts with just one. The tiny seed in time becomes a large tree. The phrase to describe the large tree just means one whose circumference is equal to that of your arms and clasped hands.

If you tried to hug three different trees for example If the first was small perhaps you could hold it within both hands together, thumbs touching and fingers touching. The second medium size you could reach around it to clasp your hands easily but only by putting the side of your face against the bark. The third one larger still you could just barley reach around to touch your fingertips together. I hope this helps.

Such measures are inexact and precision does not add to the lesson. "As big around as you can reach" just means plenty big.